# Jersey restful service communication (IncompatibleClassChangeError)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, simplehttpserver

I`ve created a restful service facade based on jersey 1.12 on the JDK 1.6 http server. When I start my application in eclipse everything works fine. I can communicate with the facade without any troubles but when I start my application via the console with my startup script I got an IncompatibleClassChangeError when I access the service.

I was able to narrow down the problem. The problem is by sending the response. Because I can communicate with the service normally (the request is processed) but I don´t get a response.  Do you have any clue about this?

startup script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
libpath=
for i in $(ls lib/*|grep ".jar"); do 
    libpath=$( echo "$i:$libpath"); 
done
java -cp "$(echo $libpath)build/jar/myjar.jar" org.....Startup
```

Exception that will be thrown

```
WARNUNG: Class org....facade.ServiceFacadeImpl is ignored as an instance is registered in the set of singletons
Call getMutationList: NP_005378
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status does not implement the requested interface javax.ws.rs.core.Response$StatusType
```

Part of my facade

```
@GET
@Path("/mutations/{id}/{from}/{size}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public MutationPosContainer getMutationList(@PathParam("id") String id,
        @PathParam("from") Integer from, @PathParam("size") Integer size) {
    ...
    if (posContainer == null)
        throw new BadRequestException();
    else
        return posContainer;
}
```

Application Handler

```
public class SnapDbApplication extends Application {
  private ServiceFacade facade;

  public SnapDbApplication(ServiceFacade facade) {
      this.facade = facade;
  }

  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
      Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
      s.add(this.facade.getClass());
      return s;
  }


  @Override
  public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
      Set<Object> s = new HashSet<Object>();
      s.add(this.facade);
      return s;
  } 
}
```

Edit: classpath

```
java -cp 
lib/xstream-1.4.2.jar:lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar:lib/xml-resolver-1.2.jar:lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar:
lib/wstx-asl-3.2.9.jar:lib/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar:lib/woden-impl-dom-1.0M9.jar:lib/woden-impl-commons-1.0M9.jar:
lib/woden-api-1.0M9.jar:lib/tribes-6.0.16.jar:lib/snpxsd.jar:
lib/regexp-1.2.jar:lib/org.springframework.web.struts-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:
lib/org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:
lib/org.springframework.web.servlet-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:
lib/org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:
...
:lib/jersey-server-1.12.jar:lib/jersey-multipart-1.12.jar:lib/jersey-json-1.12.jar:
lib/jersey-core-1.12.jar:lib/jersey-client-1.12.jar:lib/jaxws-tools-2.1.3.jar:lib/jaxen-1.1.1.jar:lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.7.jar:
lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar:lib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar:
lib/jalopy-1.5rc3.jar:lib/httpcore-4.0.jar:
lib/http-20070405.jar:lib/hamcrest-library-1:build/jar/myapp.jar
org.startup.Startup
```

Comment: Seem to be a classpath problem. Can you post the classpath used?

Comment: Eclipse apparently runs with a different classpath or JVM version.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way to see the applicatoin startup command from eclipse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably have an incompatible version of jsr311 in your classpath (see [1](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/unit-test-jersey-rest-call-with-jersey-test-framework-td5847765.html)). Remove it and it should run fine.